# Ways to get the code hash of a contract by a given address

Tags: ink, pallet-contracts, code-hash

I've been wondering how I can access a contract's code hash. I see that from ink version 3.0.1, there is a function inside the ink_env crate **code_hash** but even when updating to the following version, I don't have access to it. Is there any other way of doing this or a similar one, just to retrieve the code hash, i.e from the **"metadata.json"** of the contract or the **".contract"** file?

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the code, it looks like the code has been just [landed](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1205), maybe that's why you don't have access to it.

> Is there any other way of doing this or a similar one, just to retrieve the code hash, i.e from the "metadata.json" of the contract or the ".contract" file?

Assuming you don't need to read the code hash on-chain and you just need to obtain the code hash of a given wasm file, then it should be rather simple.

Per [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0a7e5ea46a17d71818eef8216e24eef0565bab57/frame/contracts/src/wasm/prepare.rs#L503), the `code_hash` is nothing else but the hash of the wasm code according to the specified hasher. This is chain dependent, but [more](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/e7dc0c7a7f481e7ea24e1794f147decd14814c53/runtime/src/lib.rs#L166) often than not it [is](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/polkadot-parachains/canvas-kusama/src/lib.rs#L162) blake2-256 hasher (or more specifically, it [is](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0a7e5ea46a17d71818eef8216e24eef0565bab57/primitives/core/hashing/src/lib.rs#L45) the blake2b-256).

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, according to the [ink! docs](https://paritytech.github.io/ink-docs/basics/environment-functions), you should have access to [code_hash](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/fn.code_hash.html).

Make sure you're using the correct syntax. In an `#[ink(constructor)]` use `Self::env().code_hash()` or if you're trying to access the `code_hash` in an `#[ink(message)]` then use `self.env().code_hash()`.

You can see a list of all the functions available to you [here](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/#functions).

If you're asking from the `contracts-pallet` side, you can also access the code hash via:

> Chain state > Storage > contracts > codeStorage

Comment: do you know how the last approach could be achieved?

Comment: You can do manually on polkadot{.js} UI or you can use JavaScript and call the polkadot{.js} api: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#codestorageh256-optionpalletcontractswasmprefabwasmmodule

Comment: Check this out: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1967/how-do-i-get-the-code-hash-of-a-smart-contract-using-polkadot-js-api

Comment: yup but i need to access it in rust, not from the js api